# Detect if window is too wide after injecting text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Is there a cross browser window change event that fires when the window changes? What I am trying to do is detect if the window is too wide after injecting text :

HTML page is blank, then  I inject this

```
$("body").append("cdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscscdscsdcsdcsdcsdcscs");`
```

The page is too wide and I want an event to fire so I tried this but it not working?

```
$(window).change(function () {
   alert('test');
    //is the window too wide then --------- do this
});
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: By when *window changes* you mean when it changes its size (or it gets scrollbars) ?

Comment: The window is the "browser" window, so doing `$(window).on('resize', function() {...})` will capture changes in the window size, but it won't change just because you stick some mumbojumbo in there, you'll have to resize the browser for that. Your problem seems to be more related to poorly performed CSS styles ?

Comment: what css there is no css here?